# How do I pass a variable to the next page using POST

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am having some trouble with the last little thing in my project.

I can modify a record with a form on the index page, but when I have the update button call the modifyRecord page, I can't figure out how to obtain the variable for the 'reg' (reg ID from drawer2). I have it as the value (see code) but when I try to use this or store it in a variable, I get an undefined index error. Not sure what I need to be doing??

FROM INDEX.PHP: (this happens in every loop that shows a record)

```
foreach($resultdet as $res2){
printf($format, $res2['Id'], $res2['Value1'], $res2['Value2'], $res2['reg']);

echo("<form method='Post' action='modifyRecord.php'><input type ='hidden' value =".$res2['Id'].
" name = 'Id'/><input type ='hidden' value =".$res2['reg'].
" name = 'reg'/><input type = 'submit' value = 'modify' name = 'mod'/>
</form>");
}
```

I was playing around with trying to store the value in a variable: (from modifyRecord.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['mod']))
{
echo 'POST Mod is set';
$regId = $_REQUEST['reg'];
}
```

But the echo never displays...

Not sure what is going wrong. Thank You...

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the apostrophe on the values.

Try this code:

```
echo("<form method='Post' action='modifyRecord.php'><input type='hidden' value='" .
$res2['Id'] .
"' name='Id'/><input type ='hidden' value='".$res2['reg'].
"' name='reg'/><input type='submit' value='modify' name='mod'/>
</form>");
```

Comment: I added the '' around the "" and it is still having the same problem. I get an undefined index error in the line where I assign the posted value to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach ($resultdet as $res2)
{
    printf($format, $res2['Id'], $res2['Value1'], $res2['Value2'], $res2['reg']);

    $data "
    <form method='Post' action='modifyRecord.php'>
    <input type='hidden' value=\"{$res2['Id']}\" name='Id' />
    <input type='hidden' value=\"{$res2['reg']}\" name='reg' />
    <input type='submit' value='modify' name='mod' />
    </form>";

    echo $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['mod']))
{
    echo 'POST Mod is set';
    $regId = $_REQUEST['reg'];
}
```